# language compatibility in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing one web app and for that i need to use UNICODE connect in
asp.net,
my requirement is end user can enter text in any Indian language
like Marathi,Hindi,Gujarati etc.
for e.g like "orkut" has an option that user can write text in Hindi

How can i do this in asp.net
please suggest me the solution with some thread links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems everyone is suggesting text encoding methods but it sounds like the problem you have is you need an interface for users to INPUT text?

If this is the case then check out the Google Virtual Keyboard which allows you to have an on-screen keyboard which has special foreign language keys so that it is easy for users to simply click the letters to enter them:

- http://code.google.com/apis/language/virtualkeyboard/v1/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2):

You could set the encoding to UTF-8 in the [globalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element of your web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Also you could set the meta tag in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<globalization 
            requestEncoding="utf-8" 
            responseEncoding="utf-8"  />
```

The languages list which you can use can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28vs.71%29.aspx)

Another way can be creating [satellite assemblies](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893663).